# My database columns exchanged to each other

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've developed my own web based library system using Codeigniter. I'm confuse with the active records. For clear purpose, please see my code below:

```
//Add Publisher Form
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/addPublisher" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="penerbit" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Publisher</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <input type="text" name="publisher" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="website" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Website</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Contact</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telepon" class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="alamat" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <textarea name="address" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="col-lg-2"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Publisher</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


// Add Publisher @ Admin Controller
public function addPublisher()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {           
            $publisher = $this->input->post('publisher');
            $web = $this->input->post('website');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $addr = $this->input->post('address');


            if(!empty($publisher) && !empty($web) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) && !empty($addr)){
                $this->adminModel->insertPublisher($publisher, $web, $email, $phone, $addr);
                redirect ('admin/publisher');
            } else {
                redirect ('admin/publisher');
            }


            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['user'] = $session_data['user'];
            $data['pubs'] = $this->adminModel->getAllPublisher();
            $data['tittle'] = "Add Publisher Page";

            $this->load->view('admin/static/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin/static/header-nav');
            $this->load->view('admin/static/left-nav');
            $this->load->view('admin/publisher/publisher', $data);
        } else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }


// Here my adminModel for inserting records
public function insertPublisher($publisher, $web, $phone, $email, $address)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO publisher (`id_publisher`, `publiser`, `website`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `created_at`) VALUES ('', '$publisher', '$web', '$phone', '$email', '$address', NOW())");
        return $query;
    }


// The output in print_r()
stdClass Object
(
    [id_publisher] => 1
    [publisher] => Example Publishing
    [website] => example.com
    [phone] => mypublisher@local    <--- this is my point
    [email] => 1234567              <--- and this is
    [address] => asdfgj
    [create_at] => 2014-04-30 10:48:08
)
```

**My questions are:**

1. What causes exchange between "phone" and "email" column?
2. How can I sort the view of publisher alphabetically?

Many thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

check your code 
change this

```
$this->adminModel->insertPublisher($publisher, $web, $email, $phone, $addr);
                                                        ^       ^
                redirect ('admin/publisher');
```

to this

```
$this->adminModel->insertPublisher($publisher, $web, $phone,$email, $addr);
                    redirect ('admin/publisher');
```

and check your model

```
public function insertPublisher($publisher, $web, $phone, $email, $address)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO publisher (`id_publisher`, `publiser`, `website`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `created_at`) VALUES ('', '$publisher', '$web', '$phone', '$email', '$address', NOW())");
        return $query;
    }
```

for your second problem when you retrieving a data from the data you use this query

```
"select * from publisher ORDER BY publiser ASC"
```

you can get alphabetically publisher name in Ascending order

Comment: My goodness. Thanks for advice me @Mohit Jain. You're awesome

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about the variable that you're printing in the 'print_r()', did you printed it after inserting to the DB?

As i understand your question, the reason is the order of the fields in the DB.

Comment: Mohit Jain's advise did solve my problem. I inspect for two days and the problem is in my controller. One more question if allowed, how to sort the view of all publishers alphabetically? I used 'sort' function in iteration and get error

Comment: This answer should rather be in a comment